# Inheritance: accessing parent member

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`

```
public partial class RAT : Form
```

and have another class inherited from `RAT`

```
class CAD : RAT
```

When i create instance of `CAD`, I want `RAT`(which is actually a from) size to be changed, and when i dispose `CAD` object, I want `RAT` back to original.

`CAD` Constructor:

```
    public CAD()
    {            
        base.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(805, 700);
    }
```

`CAD` Destructor:

```
    ~CAD()
    {
        base.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(805, 300);
    }
```

But the problem is, its not executing this code. Its not updating the `size` of the form. But when I update it in `RAT` it works perfectly:

```
            CAD CADObject = new CAD();
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(805, 700);
```

I think I am accessing parent class members in a right way. Then what could be the issue?

**Additional:**

After that i tried to add a control from `CAD` constructor:

```
    public CAD()
    {            
        TextBox sample = new TextBox();
        sample.Multiline = true;
        sample.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 500);
        sample.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 100);
        base.Controls.Add(sample);   //here `base` refers to `RAT` class
    }
```

But this code didn't work as well.

**Whole scenario:**

`RAT` is form. `CAD` is a simple class inherited from `RAT`. `CAD` object is created on a buttonclick from `RAT`. `CAD` has some extra features of the program so i want to update the `RAT`'s UI by adding some additional controls to `RAT` and increase its size, and update them from `CAD` `methods` and `properties`.

The program is very simple. I just want to access parent members from child class. I know I can do it all in `RAT`, but I was trying to access it from child class. That should have worked.

**Complete Code:**

```
namespace RAT_Controller
{
    public partial class RAT : Form
    {
        public RAT()
        {
            InitializeComponent();              
        }

        CAD CADObject;
        bool CADObjectCreated = false;

        private void btnCADInitializer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CADObjectCreated)
            {
                CADObject = new CAD();
                CADObjectCreated = true;
            }
            else
            {
                CADObject.Dispose();
                CADObjectCreated = false;
            }           
        }
    }

    class CAD : RAT
    {
        public CAD()
        {        
            base.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(805, 700);  //updating form size
            sample = new TextBox();
            sample.Multiline = true;
            sample.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 500);
            sample.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 100);
            base.Controls.Add(sample);    //adding control to form
        }

        TextBox sample;        

        ~CAD()
        {
            sample.Dispose();
            base.Controls.Remove(sample);  //removing control from form
            base.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(805, 300);   //updating form size
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you set the *size* in a finalizer? That's very strange.

Comment: @JonSkeet I couldn't understand your question... and even if i add a control e.g. `TextBox` from `CAD`, it also doesn't work. Size is not the only problem

Comment: You've declared a finalizer (`~CAD()`) and you're changing the size within it. That seems like a very strange thing to do. It looks like it should be fine from an inheritance perspective though - please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I suspect it actually lies elsewhere.

Comment: But you haven't provided a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, so we can't reproduce it. Cut it down to the bare minimum required to demonstrate the problem, and edit your question with that.

Comment: @JonSkeet kindly check the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32540/discussion-between-shaharyar-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: No, I'm about to lose network connectivity. I'll look when I get a chance.

Comment: I think you didn't understand inheritance correctly. You can't create a second (inherited) object and assume it alters your current object. They are completely seperate (two seperate forms). Also, modifying an object in the finalizer (there is no such thing as a destructor in .NET!) makes no sense because just after the finalizer the object is thrown away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CAD` is a completely new form, which you never show. The form that is on the screen is never changed. Instead of making `CAD` inherit from `RAD`, you should give it a field `RAD form`, and access the form through that field.

You've also got a suspicious finalizer. It won't run when you expect it to, and when it does run, I suspect it won't do what you want it to. In particular, it *isn't* called as soon as you call `Dispose`.

```
class CAD
{
    RAT form;

    public CAD(RAT form)
    {
        this.form = form;
        // Now the CAD class maintains a reference to the form it is
        // supposed to change. This field can be used in other methods
        // when it is time to remove the extra controls and restore
        // the size, like so:
        // form.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(805, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: Completely understood what you explained. But now how will I achieve this? i couldn't get what you said this `give it a field RAD form, and access the form through that field.`

Comment: Yes it works !! But one thing i couldn't understand, when i instantiate `CAD` why does it call `RAT` constructor again(again means it is already running so constructor would have been called earlier)?

Comment: @Shaharyar: Because CAD inherits from RAT. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/constructors.html

Comment: @Shaharyar Note that in the code I put in here, I have just `class CAD`, not `class CAD : RAT`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Your articles are really very detailed and full of easy understandable examples. Now every thing is clear